# HTML Malicious file detected in PDF file download link from WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, pdf, download

I've coded a whole template for WordPress. Then I added a PDF file to the Media folder, and added an anchor  link to access and download it. All works fine.

Then an user reported me that his Web Browser popped up an Alert, Might be viruses, spyware or other potentially unwanted programs in the file he tries to download.

It's a PDF manual from my company, nothing dangerous, but I don't want future customers find this kind of Alert.

Do you think is there any way to make all bit more secure for Web Browsers or Antivirus?

I wrote something like:

```
<a href="https://www.mypage.com/uploads/manual.pdf">DOWNLOAD MANUAL</a>
```

The user was using Google Chrome and McAffee antivirus in his computer.

Comment: You could try to embed the pdf with Google's PDF viewer. Use this url: `http://docs.google.com/gview?url=YOUR_PDF_URL&embedded=true" style="width:100%; height:1000px;`, just change `YOUR_PDF_URL` to the file path.

Answer (score 1):

Having dealt with 100's WordPress Security issues, and those messages, there are several things you can try.

1.) Upload the pdf to Google Drive and then try to download it. Google will tell you if there is a problem with it. Doesn't matter where it came from, if the computer that generated it had malware, it could actually be infected.

2.) Scan your WordPress installation with Sucuri's site scanner. https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/ If there is a problem, it will let you know. Security plugins are like having a shotgun in your home, by the time they detect something, it is already to late.

3.) Compress the PDF as a Zip file and upload that to the media folder. Try linking that and see if they still get the error.

4.) Check with McAfee to make sure your site is not blacklisted. You can check at MX Tools to see if you are on any of the blacklists. If you are, you have to get them cleared.

Hope that helps, let us know how it goes.